# How to use having count less than another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble with my MySQL query. I want to show the id FROM one table using left join 3 another table.

**What do I want is** :

1. Show id IS NULL in 1 of another table
2. And having COUNT() < (get column in another table)

I tried this but it is still wrong:

```
SELECT p.id FROM penerimaan AS p 
LEFT JOIN perangkat AS per ON per.id_penerimaan=p.id
LEFT JOIN permintaan AS pa ON pa.id=p.id_permintaan
LEFT JOIN konfirmasi_permintaan AS k ON k.id_permintaan=pa.id
WHERE per.id_penerimaan IS NULL
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING COUNT(per.id_penerimaan) < k.jumlahConfirm //how to get column in another table
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

the table I have

```
table permintaan
id        jumlah        status
2         3             Confirmed
3         5             Confirmed
-----------------------------------------------
table penerimaan
id        id_permintaan    date  
1         2                2017-07-12
2         3                2017-08-12
-----------------------------------------------
table konfirmasi_permintaan
id        id_permintaan       jumlahConfirmed
1         2                   3
2         3                   3
-----------------------------------------------
table perangkat
id        id_penerimaan      serial        type
1         1                  766544        SG90D-08-AS
2         1                  552411        SLM2008T-EU
3         1                  552411        SLM2008T-TU
4         2                  561434        SG95-24-AS
```

I desired result like this

```
id_penerimaan
2
```

though id_penerimaan in table perangkat IS NULL but still show, because count(perangkat.id_penerimaan) is 2 in table perangkat less than jumlahConfirm in table konfirmasi_permintaan

Thank you

Comment: `COUNT(per.id_penerimaan)` only counts the non-null values. But `WHERE per.id_penerimaan IS NULL` means you only return the null rows, so the count will always be 0.

Comment: Could you show some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: I updated my question, please check again :) @Barmar

Comment: When I try your sample data, I never get `per.id_penerimaan = NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `WHERE per.id_penerimaan` seems to solve the problem. You also have to add `k.jumlahConfirmed` to the `SELECT` list, because `HAVING` can only access values in the select list, not columns from the original tables.

```
SELECT p.id, k.jumlahConfirmed FROM penerimaan AS p 
LEFT JOIN perangkat AS per ON per.id_penerimaan=p.id
LEFT JOIN permintaan AS pa ON pa.id=p.id_permintaan
LEFT JOIN konfirmasi_permintaan AS k ON k.id_permintaan=pa.id
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING COUNT(per.id_penerimaan) < k.jumlahConfirmed
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08162aa/6)